# Webview with custom font and local images

Tags: java, android, fonts, webview

I would like to display a webview with local images and text with a custom font.
Both separately works fine with using `mywebview.loadDataWithBaseURL()`.
Because my local Images where on the sdcard in different folders and my custom Font is located in the asset/fonts folder of the app, I can't achieve the solution with `loadDataWithBaseURL` with my understanding.

Does anyone have a hint or solution ?

regards
mcfly

Thanks a lot for he hint with the contentprovider. I guess this will be the solution for me. But it doesn't work for me. I implemented the contentprovider based on an example of an android forum. The webview displays only my text, but no pictures. I set debug breakpoints in all methods of the content-provider, but the app doesn't go through that code.
I added my code for this issue, perhabs someone do see the problem ?

**ContentProvider Class**

```
class LocalFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
private static final String URI_PREFIX = "content://myapp.pictures";

public static String constructUri(String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    return uri.isAbsolute() ? url : URI_PREFIX + url;
}

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir() + uri.getPath());      
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    return parcel;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] as, String s, String[] as1, String s1) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s, String[] as) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
}
```

}

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

**My HTML**

```
<img width="120" height="120"  src="content://myapp.pictures/images/example/example1.jpg"  style="float:right;clear:right;margin:0 5px 0 0;">
```

Comment: try access images with ContentProvider , for me this worked.

Comment: please post the code segments that you have already tried

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Thanks a lot for the hint with the contentprovider. I guess this will be the solution for me, but I didn't get it to work. I added my code, perhabs someone see's my problem ?